# Destructive version of `Array#first` and `Array#last`

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there a library that provides destructive version of `Array#first` and `Array#last`? if not, what is the most efficient way to implement them? Something like this:

```
a = [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]
a.first!(2) # => [:a, :b]
a # => [:c, :d, :e]
a.last!(1) # => [:e]
a # => [:c, :d]
```

Comment: Sincerely you don't need a library for such a trivial task

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for `Array#shift` and `Array#pop`?

Comment: That seems right. I didn't know that they can take parameters.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html <-- Probably one of the most valuable documents for a Rubyist. Hard to keep it all in your head at once, but I like to look it over now again to see what I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `Array#slice!` method as below:

```
p RUBY_VERSION
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.slice!(0)
p a
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.slice!(0,2)
p a
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.slice!(-1)
p a
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.slice!(-3,3)
p a
```

*Output:*

```
"2.0.0"
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2]
```